# How to apply datatable filter when my table is passed from js?

Tags: cakephp, datatable

I have js code which gets results from a query and pastes table to a div.So table is created in js and set with js.how do I apply datatables filter in such a case?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using ajax request filter ,So url parameter filter may help :
for example : 
This is your ajax get request url :

```
$.get(root_url+'index/user?id='+id+'&name='+name+'&gender='+gender, function(response){
            console.log(response); 
        });
```

And this how you can caught those parameter in cakephp

```
public function user(){
if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
    $id = $this->request->getQuery('id');
    $name = $this->request->getQuery('name');
    $gender = $this->request->getQuery('gender');

    $condition = [];
    if ($id){
        $condition = ['Users.id' => $id];
    }
    if (name) {
        $condition = ['Users.name' => $name];
    }
    if (gender) {
        $condition = ['Users.gender' => $gender];
    }
    $user = $this->Users->find()
    ->select([
            'Users.id',
            'Users.name',
            'Users.gender',
            'Users.create_date',])
    ->where(condition);

    response = ['user' => $user];
    return $this->response->withType('application/json')
        ->withStringBody(json_encode($response));
} else {
    return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'pages','action' => 'error404']);
}
```

}