# How can i merge multiples arrays with the same key?

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a search function to filter the fields. When I pass filter on different fields the function works correctly. But when I ask for a filter with the same field and different values ​​it returns only the last value.

My functio:

```
public function setParams($params) {
        $filter = [];


    if(isset($params['filter'])) {
       $param = $params['filter'];
       $arrs = explode(',', $param);
       foreach($arrs as $arr) {
         $arr1 = explode(':', $arr);
         $arr2 = [$arr1[0] => $arr1[1]];
         $filter = array_merge($filter, $arr2);
       }
       $filter = str_replace(' ', '', $filter);
   }

$ress = ['filter' => $filter];
return $ress;
```

Ex:
If I want filter id1 and id2: 
localhost/project/api/Articles?filter=id:1,id:2

But I get just id2 in response

```
Ex: "data": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Sao Paulo",
                "shortname": "SP",
                "uf": "SP",
                "status": true,
                "created": "2019-07-23T14:17:43+00:00",
                "modified": "2019-08-22T12:32:21+00:00",
            }
```

If I pass:
localhost/project/api/Articles?filter=id:1,uf:SP
I get the corretly response:

```
Ex: "data": [


 {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Sao Paulo",
            "shortname": "SP",
            "uf": "SP",
            "status": true,
            "created": "2019-07-23T14:17:43+00:00",
            "modified": "2019-08-22T12:32:21+00:00",
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Ribeirão Preto",
            "shortname": "RP",
            "uf": "SP",
            "status": true,
            "created": "2019-07-23T14:17:43+00:00",
            "modified": "2019-08-22T12:32:21+00:00",
        }
```

What I want is:
?filter=id:1,id:2

```
Response: "data": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Ribeirao Preto",
                    "shortname": "RP",
                    "uf": "SP",
                    "status": true,
                    "created": "2019-07-23T14:17:43+00:00",
                    "modified": "2019-08-22T12:32:21+00:00",
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Sao Paulo",
                    "shortname": "SP",
                    "uf": "SP",
                    "status": true,
                    "created": "2019-07-23T14:17:43+00:00",
                    "modified": "2019-08-22T12:32:21+00:00",
                }
```

I think my problem is the array_merge, when it is the same field it replaces the first value with the last one.

Somenone can help me?

Comment: What is your final output if you pass two ids? `{"id":"1"}` This is if you pass one value right? If you pass two values, what does it look like ? `{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"}` ?

Comment: When i pass 2 ids then return just the last one. If i pass id:1,id:2. I got id:2

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need `array_merge`? You can simply:

```php
$filter[] = $arr2;
```

Comment: Then correct your example with exact desired output of `$filters`, from your example you just need all ids.

Comment: Sorry, but I dont understand. I dont want all ids, i want just id1 and id2. Your example return all ids.

Comment: `setParams()` returns you only last paramount like this. I have no idea how your others function work, so I ask you for exact output of `setParams()` function.

Comment: The output with $filter[]=$arr2 dont works because return an array inside another array

Comment: @Bruny and what do you need? :) Just give an example!

Comment: I have a example in my question. The last example is exacly what i need. I want pass id:1,id:2,id:3.. But array_merge dont works with repeated key. And i dont know how do this without array_merge. Because in the end i need merge all to get a json response.

Comment: @Bruny I don't know what version of api are you using, is it's built by you? I need to understand, what is required to get desired output, what data format, where the result of setParams() passed?

Answer (score 0):

I think you method gonna help you. if you want to filter like you said: 
Your url should be like this it will be easy:

```
localhost/project/api/Articles?filterbyid=1,2
```

NOT like this `localhost/project/api/Articles?filter=id:1,id:2` it will make difficult to slipt string.

Using this to retrieve your filter string : `string_filer = $this->request->getData('filterbyid')` and this clean your string `$str_clean = preg_replace(',', '',$pattern);`
after you got those you just slit it into array using this `$array_filter = str_split($str_clean , 1);` so you will got two array 1 and 2.

finally what you want that to data so you just using `in_array` method check and compare you data and that filter array done.

please let me know if you still want something more.

Comment: Its a good way, butI use the filter to filter another fields too. Like name, uf and another fields from another tables. So i cant have a variable like filterbyid.

Comment: Hello @Bruny,
check this link it will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57967839/how-to-apply-datatable-filter-when-my-table-is-passed-from-js/57971779#57971779